# Index number for records within a pipe-delimited field inside a csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I have a csv that I'm bringing into a SQL table.  The csv has a field within it for CrimeType.  That field is pipe delimited.  So, I'm using cross apply to break up the pipe, like this:

```
SELECT CrimeRecords.CaseNum, CrimeRecords.Offense, PrimaryCrime.PrimaryCrime
FROM (SELECT CaseNum ,x.i.value('.','varchar(20)') AS Offense 
            FROM (SELECT CaseNum, CONVERT(XML,'<i>'+REPLACE(CrimeType, '|', '</i><i>') + '</i>') AS d 
                        FROM CrimeView.dbo.tblCrimeData)x1 CROSS APPLY d.nodes('i') AS x(i)) AS CrimeRecords
```

Can someone help me add a step to create a field for a sequence number?  Basically I just want to return the order of the items in the pipe.

For rows like:

```
1, Burglary|Assault
2, Burglary
3, Assault|Assault-Weapon|Theft
```

My result table would look like this:

```
CaseNum     CrimeType        SeqNum
1           Burglary         1
1           Assault          2
2           Burglary         1
3           Assault          1
3           Assault-Weapon   2
3           Theft            3
```

Edit to show that the Sequence Number resets for each CaseNum.

Edit tags to clarify that this is Microsoft SQL, not MySQL.

Comment: Wouldn't a sequence field (ID) in the table be enough for that purpose?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I need the numbers to relate to the CaseNum.  So for CaseNum #2, the SeqNum needs to start over at 1.

Comment: Ah! You may want to do an edit to clearly show that the sequence number resets each time...

Comment: @AlexisWilke Good point, thank you.  Edited.

Comment: I modified my answer to include partitioning by case number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try including the ROW_NUMBER() function in your SELECT statement (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

i.e.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CrimeRecords.CaseNum ORDER BY CrimeRecords.CaseNum) As Idx, CrimeRecords.CaseNum, CrimeRecords.Offense, PrimaryCrime.PrimaryCrime
FROM (SELECT CaseNum ,x.i.value('.','varchar(20)') AS Offense 
            FROM (SELECT CaseNum, CONVERT(XML,'<i>'+REPLACE(CrimeType, '|', '</i><i>') + '</i>') AS d 
                        FROM CrimeView.dbo.tblCrimeData)x1 CROSS APPLY d.nodes('i') AS x(i)) AS CrimeRecords
```

Edit:  Included Partition By to reset the sequence for each case.

Comment: I was just experimenting with that- my only concern is that I want the SeqNum to match the order from the pipe.  I guess I don't trust the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a simple table  **CrimeRecords**    like    **CaseNum  |  CrimeType**
you have to do something like this

```
SELECT  CaseNum,CrimeType, @row:=@row+1  SeqNum
FROM  CrimeRecords a JOIN    (SELECT @row := 0) b;
```

ok.. I cant see crearly in your query and i cant try it in a db, buy try to use the query i shared.
It is just an example to show how you can add numbers in order 1,2,3...x from some elements in the rows.. so try to mix it code in your query and reestart the @row each time the group change..
so you ll get it

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't simple.  It is like CaseNum, CrimeType - but CrimeType has a pipe within that field. So it is comma-delimited with a pipe-delimited field.  I just edited my original post to clear things up a bit.

Comment: ok.. I cant see clearly in your query and i cant try it in a db, buy try to use the query i shared. It is just an example to show how you can add numbers in order 1,2,3...x from some elements in the rows.. so try to mix it code in your query and reestart the @row each time the group change (CaseNum).. so you ll get it